# How do I make the bottom two drop-downs invisible until a selection is made in the first drop-down?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Here is my code. All three dropdowns are visible which is wrong. I only want the fist dropdown to be visible (to which upon selection should make one of the other two visible depending upon what option is chosen) What's crazy is when I insert a sample code in to my html, the ng-if works.

```
             <!-- real code <status.html>

     <select class="form-control" id="substatus" [(ngModel)]="ddlCorrespondenceStatus">
        <option value="M">Manual</option>
        <option value="G">Complete</option>

      </select>
                 <select *ng-if="ddlCorrespondenceStatus == 'M'" class="form-control" id="substatus" [(ngModel)]="ddlCorrespondenceSubStatus">
          <option value="U">UnroutedTest</option>
          <option value="R">Routed</option>
          <option value="S">Saved</option>

        </select>
        <ss-multiselect-dropdown *ng-if="{ddlCorrespondenceStatus == 'G'" class="report-multiselect"
                                 [disabled]="filterDisabled"
                                 [options]="ddlStatus"
                                 [settings]="genericSearchMSDropdownSettings"
                                 [texts]="statusMSDropdownTextSettings"
                                 [(ngModel)]="selectedStatuses"
```

Sample code below this line works inside of page, Real code above this does not

```
 (ngModelChange)="handleQueueSelection($event)">
        </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
 Sample code below this works inside the page, Real Code above does not 
 <div *ngIf="false">
          <a *ngIf="false" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

There is sysntactical error in your code. `*ng-if` is wrong syntax. The other problem is with parentheses within if condition which is wrong again.

### Fix

You must use `*ngIf` as -

```
<select *ngIf="ddlCorrespondenceStatus == 'M'" 
class="form-control" id="substatus" [(ngModel)]="ddlCorrespondenceSubStatus">
```

Comment: unfortunately that was just a typo and not the problem. It's not been fixed

Comment: it is supposed to be *ngIf and not ng-If. You were right